# How to pass active link value inside selected option function on change

Tags: angularjs

I have select and list:

```
<select ng-model="atndYearSelected" ng-options="year for year in atnd_years|orderBy:'-year'" 
        ng-change="getAttendance(selectedYear,month.number,infoList['0']['staff_id']);" class="year"></select>  

<ul class="year_selection">
  <li ng-repeat="month in monthsList" ng-class="{active_year : isActiveYear(month.number)}">
    <a href="" ng-click="setActiveYear(month.number); getAttendance(atndYearSelected,month.number,infoList['0']['staff_id']);">
      {{month.month}}
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

`getAttendance` function works fine on `ng-click` inside the list. However I cant access `month.number` value inside `ng-change`. Is there any way to access month number value?

I tried to use `ng-init` inside of the link but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`month` is only available inside your `ng-repeat` within the li. Thus `<select>` has no access to it.

The work around to this is to store it in a scope variable when `setActiveYear` of `li` is called, and you can use this scope variabl when you want to.

```
$scope.setActiveYear =  function(monthNumber){
     //...other codes
     $scope.myValue = monthNumber; 
};
```